# How to explode Python Pandas Dataframe based on string and criteria

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-explode

How to turn `StringDataFrame`:

| String |
| --- |
| Jon likes {ExplodeAnimals}. |
| Jon eats {ExplodeFruit}. |

Into this:

| String |
| --- |
| Jon likes Cats. |
| Jon likes Dogs. |
| Jon likes Tigers. |
| Jon likes Llamas. |
| Jon eats Apples. |
| Jon eats Pears. |
| Jon eats Bananas. |
| Jon eats Strawberries. |

Based on this `ThingsDataFrame`

| Thing | Type |
| --- | --- |
| Cats | animal |
| Dogs | animal |
| Tigers | animal |
| Llamas | animal |
| Apples | fruit |
| Pears | fruit |
| Bananas | fruit |
| Strawberries | fruit |

Comment: This, to me, is confusing.   What are your inputs?  What is ExplodeAnimals and ExplodeFruit?

Comment: Can you also explain how this should generalize?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

##### option 1

You can use [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)/[`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html).

```
# you could skip this mapping if you used "Jon likes {animal}."
mapper = {'ExplodeAnimals': 'animal', 'ExplodeFruit': 'fruit'}

out = (StringDataFrame['String']
  .str.extract(r'(?P<String>.*) {(?P<Type>.*)}')
  .assign(Type=lambda d: d['Type'].map(mapper))
  .merge(ThingsDataFrame, on='Type')
  .assign(String=lambda d: d['String']+' '+d['Thing'])
  [['String']]
)

print(out)
```

Output:

```
                  String
0         Jon likes Cats
1         Jon likes Dogs
2       Jon likes Tigers
3       Jon likes Llamas
4        Jon eats Apples
5         Jon eats Pears
6       Jon eats Bananas
7  Jon eats Strawberries
```

##### option 2

probably less efficient but more versatile, using the curly bracket notation to perform brace expansion (with the [`braceexpand`](https://pypi.org/project/braceexpand/) module):

```
# pip install braceexpand
from braceexpand import braceexpand

mapper = ThingsDataFrame.groupby('Type')['Thing'].agg(','.join)

(StringDataFrame['String']
 .str.replace(r'(?<={)([^{}]*)(?=})', lambda m: mapper.get(m.group(1)))
 .apply(lambda x: list(braceexpand(x)))
 .explode()
)
```

NB. simplifying the `StringDataFrame` input to:

```
                String
0  Jon likes {animal}.
1    Jon eats {fruit}.
```

Output:

```
0           Jon likes Cats.
0           Jon likes Dogs.
0         Jon likes Tigers.
0         Jon likes Llamas.
1          Jon eats Apples.
1           Jon eats Pears.
1         Jon eats Bananas.
1    Jon eats Strawberries.
Name: String, dtype: object
```

This enables you to do funky stuff like:

```
print(StringDataFrame)
#                                  String
# 0  Jon likes {animal} that eat {fruit}.

print(ThingsDataFrame)
#     Thing    Type
# 0    Cats  animal
# 1    Dogs  animal
# 2  Apples   fruit
# 3   Pears   fruit

mapper = ThingsDataFrame.groupby('Type')['Thing'].agg(','.join)

(StringDataFrame['String']
 .str.replace(r'(?<={)([^{}]*)(?=})', lambda m: mapper.get(m.group(1)))
 .apply(lambda x: list(braceexpand(x)))
 .explode()
)

# 0    Jon likes Cats that eat Apples.
# 0     Jon likes Cats that eat Pears.
# 0    Jon likes Dogs that eat Apples.
# 0     Jon likes Dogs that eat Pears.
# Name: String, dtype: object
```

Comment: good answer - pretty much how I would answer this.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. StringDataFrame has a lot of other rows of data and I need the solution to "explode" (expand) the StringDataFrame with the added rows while keeping the other unrelated rows of data intact. Your solution seems to create a new separate dataframe. Can you show how to modify the existing StringDataFrame? Thank you!

Comment: @user1574881 which approach do you want to use? With the second one you can just assign the output of `StringDataFrame['String'].str.replace(...).apply(...)` to your original column, then `explode` the DataFrame. With the first one, it requires a few more steps. Please update your example in the question.

Comment: @mozway I found the answer I was looking for here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76245434/how-to-explode-python-pandas-dataframe-and-merge-strings-from-other-dataframe#76245692 Thank you for your help.