# How to explode Python Pandas Dataframe and merge strings from other dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-explode

`Dataframe1` has a lot of rows and columns of data. One column is `Text`. Certain rows in `Text` column have strings and some strings include within the strings this `{ExplodeEList2}`

How to explode (expand) those specific rows of `Dataframe1` and replace `{ExplodeEList2}` in each string with each name contained in the separate dataframe `EList2['Name']`? Thank you! I've been banging my head against my keyboard all day trying to solve this.

`Dataframe1`:

| Text |
| --- |
| Unrelated data |
| Random sample text {ExplodeElist2} and more random sample text. |
| Other unrelated data |

`EList2`:

| Name |
| --- |
| Jack |
| Jon |
| Sally |

How do I generate this in `Dataframe1`:

| Text |
| --- |
| Unrelated data |
| Random sample text Jack and more random sample text. |
| Random sample text Jon and more random sample text. |
| Random sample text Sally and more random sample text. |
| Other unrelated data |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) to process all the `Text` values in `DataFrame1` which contain the string `ExplodeElist2`, replacing the string with a list of replaced values. You can then [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) that list:

```py
mask = DataFrame1['Text'].str.contains('{ExplodeElist2}')
DataFrame1.loc[mask, 'Text'] = DataFrame1.loc[mask, 'Text'].apply(lambda s:[s.replace('{ExplodeElist2}', n) for n in Elist2['Name']])
DataFrame1 = DataFrame1.explode('Text').reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output (for your sample data):

```
                                                Text
0                                     Unrelated data
1  Random sample text Jack and more random sample...
2  Random sample text Jon and more random sample ...
3  Random sample text Sally and more random sampl...
4                               Other unrelated data
```